# Tightly couple view : on POST method send plain values to server : Using any tool hacker can bombard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have a Add/Edit user page where I have used tightly couple view. So whenever end-user is going to Add/Edit user (in our term POST method), all the values which are sending to server are plain text. End-user can easily modify the request or server can be bombarded by same requests just changing some value. May I know how can I restrict it?

Comment: This might be tough to do. It's really the job of the server to verify the data is correct/valid. This is true when dealing with security issues such as SQL injection. If you're using MVC 3 to help you with POSTing form values, they have a some attributes you can specify on fields. Eg. required values, allowed values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the anti-forgery token helpers built in to MVC3 (designed to prevent exactly the cross-site requests you're talking about):

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/